# How to I add \textit into a table and color to different parts of my table?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm working on creating tables that are both informative and aesthetically pleasing and can't get Latex to allow me to change the text font to \textit within an tabular and also it doesn't allow me to add color as well. Does anyone know how to do that?

The code I've used is shown below:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
    \rowcolor{iceberg}
 \textit{ How do the companies that sell information systems guide their clients to use this information and knowledge of client behavior?} \end{tabular}} \\ 
\hline
    Case firms & \textbf{A1} & \textbf{A2}
```

Comment: Your sample code contains neither `\textit` not `\textcolor` directives. Do please tell us *where* italics and/or color should be applied? Please also clarify if the color should pertains to the lettering or to the cell background.

Comment: @Mico I've edited in the text what I thought I could do to edit in the \textit and color for the row but by doing so I get an error on the whole document.

Comment: How or where is the color "iceberg" defined? And what does error message say?

Comment: @Mico the error say Missing } inserted. but this doesn't make sense as all { and } should be correctly placed

Comment: When I remove the \textit the rowcolor emerges, so it looks like the issue is with implementing the text adaptation.

Comment: `\rowcolor` has to come before `\multicolumn`, not in the third argument of `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit and provide only code, which a) compiles when copied, b) has all it needs, but not more (minimalistic), c) still shows your problem. // Your code unfortunately doesn't meet a). Early comments indicated flaws with c). // This will result in more helpful answers (solutions).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the "iceberg" color is defined. In the code below, I load the `xcolor` package with the option `svgnames` in order to access a prefefined color labelled "Linen". I suggest using the `p` column type, which allows automatic line breaking, for the combination of the three underlying columns.

Since there's nothing in the code that's specific to the `longtable` environment, I've chosen to employ a basic `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{array}             % for \extrarowheight macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}  % for "Linen" color
\usepackage{colortbl}          % for \rowcolor macro

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|} % sum of usable widths: 14cm
\hline
\rowcolor{Linen}
\multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr14cm+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{%
\textit{How do the companies that sell information systems 
  guide their clients to use this information and knowledge 
  of client behavior?}} \\ 
\hline
Case firms & \textbf{A1} & \textbf{A2} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Observe the use of (a) a `\rowcolor` statement *before* `\multicolumn` and (b) `\textit` *inside* the third argument of `\multicolumn`.

Comment: If you really have a long table, I recommend to use `longtblr` from `tabularray` package. And another suggestion would be to use `SetCell` instead of `multirow` or `multicolumn`. This make the code much cleaner. You can also define colours efficiently inside `longtblr`.